# Oracle SQL - Running scripts

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create an Oracle SQL script that defines the field and triggers for multiple tables as part of my initialization for the implementation of a new project.  A sample of what I'm trying to do is shown here;

```
ALTER TABLE TBL_SAP_VENDORS
    DROP COLUMN UPT_TS;
ALTER TABLE TBL_SAP_VENDORS
ADD (
 UPT_TS TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 );
-- The automatic update of fields has to be performed using a trigger 
-- First we drop the trigger incase it already exists
drop trigger vendors_updt_mark;
-- Then add the trigger deffinition
CREATE TRIGGER vendors_updt_mark
before insert or update
 on TBL_SAP_VENDORS
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 :new.UPT_TS := SYSTIMESTAMP;
END;


-- INVENTORY
ALTER TABLE TBL_SAP_INVENTORY
    DROP COLUMN UPT_TS;
ALTER TABLE TBL_SAP_INVENTORY
ADD (
 UPT_TS TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 );
-- The automatic update of fields has to be performed using a trigger 
-- First we drop the trigger incase it already exists
drop trigger inventory_updt_mark;
-- Then add the trigger deffinition
CREATE TRIGGER inventory_updt_mark
before insert or update
 on TBL_SAP_INVENTORY
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 :new.UPT_TS := SYSTIMESTAMP;
END;
```

When I try executing this in the Oracle SQL Developer I get the message :

```
Table TBL_SAP_VENDORS altered.


Table TBL_SAP_VENDORS altered.


Trigger VENDORS_UPDT_MARK dropped.


Trigger VENDORS_UPDT_MARK compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
6/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" 
Errors: check compiler log
```

When I open up the compile log I see:

`Error(5,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER"`

How do I run these commands, of which I have about 20 to run in a single script?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to end the creation of a trigger (or any PL/SQL object, for that matter), with a slash on its own line.

```
...

CREATE TRIGGER vendors_updt_mark
before insert or update
 on TBL_SAP_VENDORS
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 :new.UPT_TS := SYSTIMESTAMP;
END;
/

....
```

Comment: ... because the tool sql*plus requires this, and SQL Developer uses sql*plus when runnin a script.